# How to handle large numbers in python, django models for mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, floating-point

How to handle large numbers in python and django models for mysql datatype?
I want to store large decimal numbers e.g mass of the Sun in kg
`(1.98847±0.00007)×10^30 kg`
and other large numbers of physics and astronomy.

What `max_digits` and `decimal_places` will I need?

For simple longitude, latitude I use 11,6:

```
models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=6, null=False)


>>> s = 1.9884723476542349808764
>>> s
1.988472347654235
>>>

>>> c = 9.961558465069068e-35
>>> c
9.961558465069068e-35
>>> Decimal(c)
Decimal('9.9615584650690682798407470173147606387909020112701851758062095613274216457861081111717165524621631078616701415739953517913818359375E-35')
>>>
```

Comment: you should not first use a float, and then covert it to a decimal, since then of course the precision is lost. You should *directly* use a `Decimal`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What `max_digits` and `decimal_places` do I use for giant number like `9.961558465069068e-35`? because I have to fit this into the mysql database.

Comment: in that case you will need something like `max_digits=51` and `decimal_places=51`. This will thus represent values between `0` and `1` with a "resolution" of `10e-51`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Why 51? How did you arrive at 51?

Comment: Because you have 16 digits in your number, and that is located 35 digits after the comma, so 16+35=51.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Great. Thank you !!!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Does python or MySQL automatically shifts decimal point to accommodate the number in the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work with a [**`Decimal`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal), not a `float`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

s = Decimal('1.9884723476542349808764')
```

For example:

```
>>> Decimal('1.9884723476542349808764')
Decimal('1.9884723476542349808764')
>>> Decimal('1.9884723476542349808764') * 3
Decimal('5.9654170429627049426292')
```

A `Decimal` is a number type that can work with arbitrary precision. If you work with a `DecimalField`, than this will also provide `Decimal` values. If you however write a `float` to that `DecimalField`, then rounding errors can occur because of the limited mantissa of a `float`.